# Making a terminal command 'permanent'

Tags: command-line

I would like to make Ubuntu "remember" the following command line (for trackpad to work):

```
xinput set-prop "Cypress APA Trackpad (cyapa)" "Synaptics Finger" 15 20 256
```

is there a way to make this permanent, so I dont have to type it in every time I start the computer?

Cheers!

Luke

Comment: You mean when using a desktop? Or does this also need to work when in a terminal?

Comment: I would think the command is `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 5):

## Starting script when computer starts

I found out way to make program run when machine boots. Just type in **Terminal**

1. `cd /etc/init.d` - going to init directory
2. And now we gonna write script that will do your command. For that type `sudo gedit trackpad` and paste this code in

   ```
    #! /bin/sh
    # /etc/init.d/trackpad
    #
    xinput set-prop "Cypress APA Trackpad (cyapa)" "Synaptics Finger" 15 20 256
   ```

   Save that file. With this step you have created script that **must** run and 'start' your **trackpad**. **Important** to make file executable using `chmod 755 fileName`
3. Now we will need to say computer to run that script when computer boots. For that type this command:
    `sudo update-rc.d trackpad defaults`
4. Now you're done, just try to reboot computer :)

Sources:

- [Stack overflow](https://superuser.com/questions/155476/how-do-i-make-a-script-run-upon-startup-of-the-ubuntu-machine)
- [Superuser](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian)

## Starting script when user will login using 'Startup applications'

Just add that to startup, and it will work when your computer will start. To do that just go to **Unity** and search for **Startup Applications**, click **Add** and type name link **Trackpad start** and in **Command** field fill in:
`bash -c 'xinput set-prop "Cypress APA Trackpad (cyapa)" "Synaptics Finger" 15 20 256'`

---

[image]

---

Notice that second way will work only when you will log in, not when computer will start.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this command to the [bash startup file](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files) try to paste it to

```
 ~/.bash_login
```

and restart computer and see if it worked.